# Double slash problem while writing into excel sheet using pandas python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame like this:
[I have got this data frame after some manipulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wd2K.png)

When i write into excel sheet using df.to_excel(Output.xlsx,Sheet1),its getting written in excel sheet but with double slashes.[when i write into excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LYAV.png).
I dont want double slashes to appear.

Comment: Copy and paste a sample of the data frame so that we can reproduce it in the code

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
df.to_excel(Output.xlsx, sheet_name='Sheet1',encoding='utf-8')
```